# What should I do with my old memory?

Tags: memory, spare-parts

I just replaced the 2 1GB DIMMs in my MacBook Pro with 2 x 2GB DIMMs. What can I do with the old memory?

Comment: Don't think this needs to be community wiki?

Comment: Yep- you're right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't think your gonna use it again, why not [recycle it](http://www.computerhope.com/disposal.htm)?  Or you could use the sticks as a really geeky bookmark.

Answer (score 2):

Sell them? I'm sure you could make at least a little cash off them on eBay or Craigslist.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure you could simply sell it on. Especially since it's unlikely your going to reuse it as it's come out of your Mac. Is anyone else you know about to buy a similar model? Since 2g is the default maybe not..

Answer (score 1):

You can sell it, or - as tj111 noted - recycle it. Note: in EU countries computer memory is considered dangerous waste, and by law should be properly disposed by appropriate recycling company. Ask your local computer store, they will help you.
On disposing:
http://ec.europa.eu/environment/waste/weee/index_en.htm

Comment: Not just the EU - my local city has a drop-off for all electronic devices. You're not supposed to throw that stuff in the garbage anymore, I think it's state-wide.

Answer (score 1):

Give it to a local school.